# Extract results from Coverity

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, coverity

I need to find a way to extract Coverity results (new defects only) via the command line for reporting purposes.

Our team is running Coverity (version 6.5.3) on a nightly basis (linux platform), and the results can be viewed through Firefox via Coverity Connect.

When the Coverity script runs, it collects metrics via "cov-analyze" or "cov-analyze-java", then commits the results via "cov-commit-defects".

I've tried to analyze the output from the Coverity run looking for a file that shows the defects count, but my problem is that all I can find is the raw count of defects found, not the total of untriaged defects.  Clearly after the commit, Coverity knows which are new defects vs. old defects that have already been triaged, and only reports the new.

I thought maybe there'd be an export utility in Coverity, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Gotta be honest. 6.5.3 is ooooold  You really should be running 7.7 or 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you upgrade to Coverity Connect 8.0 then there is.

There is an API to export views in CC.  You can export them as either XML or CSV.  IIRC, there is a way to invoke it from cov-manage-im as well.

Comment: We're looking into upgrading right now.  Unfortunately, turn around time tends to be slow.  I'll check this out if/when we get upgraded.  Thanks.

Comment: I just tested `cov-manage-im` (which is available in 6.5.3) and it's giving me what I need.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

what about using cov-manage-im and grep'pin for `NEW`?

CMD-Line may look as following:

```
cov-manage-im --mode streams --update --name "$STREAM_NAME" --host=yourhost --user=your_user --password=your_PW | grep NEW
```

Comment: But how can you see the new ones *before* updating/commiting to the database?